# Indy - ReadLnSplit Causes NotConnected Exception when closing

Tags: sockets, exception, indy

I use TIdTCPServer and the following code to read client input :

```
repeat
    cl3:=cl3+AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLnSplit(WasSplit,#0,-1,-1,TEncoding.UTF8);
    until not WasSplit;
```

However if client is connected to the server and I close the server it raises an exception class (EIdNotConnected) whith message 'Not connected'.
If I use *ReadLn* instead *ReadLnSplit* no exception raises.

What causes this exception and how could I prevent it?

I suppose the solution is simple but I am new to sockets and Indy and I cant figure it out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the actual problem?  When you close the server, it is **supposed** to make active reading/writing operations raise an exception.  That is normal behavior for Indy.  `ReadLn()` is just as likely to raise an exception as `ReadLnSplit()` is.  Indy relies on exceptions for its internal notifications.  Just let the server handle the exception for you, so it can terminate and cleanup the thread that is managing the `TIdContext` and its connection.  The exception is in the context of that thread, the rest of your code (or your users) will not see it.

The only thing `ReadLnSplit()` does differently than `ReadLn()` is to force the IOHandler's `MaxLineAction` property to `maSplit` during that call, nothing else.  The only reason to use `ReadLnSplit()` is to handle lines that are longer than the IOHandler's `MaxLineLength` property without changing the `MaxLineLength`.  If you don't like the way `ReadLnSplit()` behaves, then don't use it.  You could just increase the value of the IOHandler's `MaxLineLength` property and call `ReadLn()` instead:

```
AContext.Connection.IOHandler.MaxLineLength := MaxInt;
cl3 := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn(#0, IndyUTF8Encoding);
```

Or you could call the overloaded version of `ReadLn()` that has an optional `AMaxLineLength` parameter:

```
cl3 := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn(#0, IdTimeoutDefault, MaxInt, IndyUTF8Encoding);
```